# Set default value as column value

Tags: plsql, oracle11gr1

i want to set default value as column for existing table, 
example : `create table t(a Number(22), b NUMBER(22)`;

i jsut want to set default value for `column B as column A`.

I know we cannot do like this, could any one suggest an alternate way to do so..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't set the default value directly in the code ?

```
if(Obj.B == null)
Obj.B = Obj.A
```

I think is not the role of the database to express this kind of rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ON INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON T
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.B IS NULL THEN
    :NEW.B := :NEW.A;
  END IF;
END T_BI;
```

Share and enjoy.